# Можно ли редактировать сообщения которое уже было уже за редактирован в python discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@client.command( pass_context = True)

async def infoq(ctx):
  embeda = discord.Embed(title = '  text', color=0xff1f1f)
  embeda.add_field(name = 'Статус',value =  '  **ofline**')
  msg = await ctx.send(embed = embeda)
  ediat = await msga.edit(embed = uembed)
  await asyncio.sleep(30) 
  await ediat.edit(embed = uembed)
```

можно ли редактировать сообщения которое уже было уже за редактирован ? или хотя бы как можно это сделать
и хотелось бы чтоб каждые 10 сек всегда изминялтся

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сообщение можно редактировать сколько угодно раз. Для периодического повторения используется `@tasks.loop()`:

```
from discord.ext import tasks

@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def update():
    await msg.edit(embed=embed)

update.start()
```

Это шаблонный код, `msg` и `embed` в нём не определены.

Comment: случаем апи не заблокают? дискорд уж очень я заметил не любит когда его апи слишком часто тыкают)

Comment: @merka написано, что можно делать 50 запросов в секунду: https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits
Если бот не популярен, то не критично.